# Twitter Search API is not returning ALL tweets on a given search

Tags: twitter

My test tweets are not showing up in the twitter search.  I have asked several other people to test this as well and only a few show up.

I am trying to track a campaign on the number of people who tweet a certain hashtag.  How am I supposed to track it accurately if the search does not give exact results?

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Take this question directly to twitter.

Answer (score 3):

I read where the API isn't extremely accurate. It only returns results after a crawl, and may not have crawled the entire database when you're searching. The API also doesn't hold on to tweets longer than a few days old.